# How to repair my mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I can't seem to connect to Mongo DB, which I've installed as a Windows Service on my local machine. I've also built a little WPF application which communicates with MongoDB. 
The errormessage:

*Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:8
4
exception: connect failed
Unclean shutdown detected.*

Comment: I did the same app architecture: WPF app and MongoDb  as a "local db" and I conclude that because of this problem MongoDb is not suitable for this kind of application, but only for highly reliable server-side platforms. Else you will be frequently visited by this problem. Better go for alternative like LiteDb or Mini-Biggy.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You should launch it with `--repair` flag.

```
mongod --repair
```

After repair is finished, stop this one and launch it normally. [Documentation on --repair option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--repair).

Comment: If the repair fails and mongod responds with an exception on a corrupted data file, remove the mongd.lock file along with the corrupt mongo data files and run mongod --repair again. You will obviously lose data with this approach, but at least you'll be able to start mongod again.

Answer (score 24):

Quicker:

```
sudo rm /data/db/mongod.lock
sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db
```

Comment: Thanks! Using the --dbpath option with the --repair flag worked for me. I had the same issue with the "unclean shutdown" (whatever that means), and when I attempted to repair I got an error stating that the default "\data\db" directory was not found. This was expected as I am using a separate location to store my logs & data. I just set the --dbpath to my custom location & worked. I haven't confirmed, but my guess is that I could use the --config "mongodb\mongod.cfg" with the --repair flag for MongoDB to use my custom settings. Odd that it wasn't reading from that file with the repair.

Comment: @Shejo284 For Windows, the command will be `mongod.exe --dbpath "C:\path\to\data" --repair`. If you get the "unclean shutdown" err, then run mongod from cmd, then press ctrl-C to shut down cleanly, and then run that command.

Comment: it works, should find dbpath by `grep dbPath /etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: Be careful with owner of lock file in case of using sudo.

Comment: I love you man. You saved me after 3 hours of struggling this.

Answer (score 14):

If you do a repair operation as root user be sure that afterwards all db files are owned by the mongodb user, otherwise mongodb will not start

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db
rm /data/db/mongod.lock
/etc/init.d/mongodb start
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ mongo 
> use dbname
> db.repairDatabase()
```

**Note** --repair functionality is also available in the shell with the db.repairDatabase() helper for the repairDatabase command.

See also http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/:

Comment: Are first lines intended to be a script example? Then prepend them with 4 spaces to format as code and not as list.

Comment: Hi, I know this is a very old question and answer. Btw for anyone that still coming to this place and you have failed to fix your corrupt collection using `--repair` mainly to ownership and everything, this magic works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [official MongoDB repo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) on Ubuntu instead of the default packages, the accepted answer **will not work**.

The `mongod` command, by default, uses `/data/db` as the [default `dbPath` config setting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-storage.dbPath) whereas `/etc/mongodb.conf` uses `/var/lib/mongodb` as the path. Therefore if you just do `mongod --repair`, it will try to repair a database at `/data/db`, which is the wrong path.

I also found that if you execute `mongod` as the `root` user, any files created will be owned by `root`, so you need to execute the repair with the `mongodb` user.

This is what I eventually did to get it to work:

```sh
sudo chown -R mongodb: /var/lib/mongodb # Just to make sure permissions are correct
sudo -u mongodb mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --repair
sudo service mongodb start
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the command as below and I think it will solve the problem:

```
cd data/

rm -rf mongod.lock*

cd ..

mongod --repair

./mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step to restart your mondoDB as fresh

1, Kill all the processes that mongod is running

> to do this forcefully kill each process that are running on port 27017(default port for mongodb)
>
> `lsof -n -i4TCP:27017`  Where 27017 is the port number the process is
>   running at
>
> this returns the process id(PID) and run
>
> `kill -9 "PID"` Replace PID with the number you get after running the
>   first command

2, restart mongo using `mongod` command