# WriteConcern detected an error in mognodb

Tags: mongodb, save, document

When I am saving documents in monogdb, getting the following error

```
"{WriteConcern detected an error 'bad offset:0 accessing file:xxxx - consider
 repairing database'. (Response was { \"err\" : \"bad offset:0 accessing file:
  xxxxx - consider repairing database\", \"code\" : 13440, \"n\" : 0, 
 \"connectionId\" : 13, \"ok\" : 1.0 }).}"
```

any help please

Comment: Did you try repairing the database?

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, the database requires repairing because it is in an `inconsistent state` due to whatever operation that caused `unexpected shutdown`.

In MongoDB `WriteConcern` provides feedback/acknowledgement in response to a write operation. There are multiple levels of WriteConcerns or guarantees that on whether the write operation was successful or not. The `WriteConcerns` levels are as follow:

1. Unacknowledged (the client does not wait for acknowledgement of write op)
2. Acknowledged (client waits for success or exception ack. of write op)
3. Journaled (mongodb sends acknowledgment only after committing the write to journal)
4. Replica Acknowledged (ack. of write op on primary and/or other members of replica set)

You can set the levels of `WriteConcerns` to any level depending on importance of write operation.

The `WriteConcern` in your case returns an exception stating that database is in an inconsistent state may/may not data might have been corrupted. In order to get back to operational mode, you need to repair the database in one of many ways.

1. Via Mongodb shell (if you can connect to MongoDb)
2. Via command line with `mongod` see below

If you can get into MongoDB shell, then you need to find the database and repair it as follow

```
use dbName
db.repairDatabase() //repairs the above database
```

If you cannot get into MongoDB shell or wish to use other method then you can use the following methods

**Repair Data files and preserve original files**

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair --repairpath /data/db0
mongod --dbpath /data/db0
```

Once the first command above complete, the newly repaired data will be under `/data/db0` directory and you can use the second command to start mongodb using repaired data. The original data files are preserved in the default `/data/db` or a custom location (if not default)

**Repair Data files WITHOUT preserve original files**

This method you only supply `--repair` and no `--repathpath` and it will attempt to repair the original data files. First you have to delete `mongod.lock` file, steps are as follow:

```
rm /data/db/mongod.lock
```

Assuming your data is in /data/db directory, if not specify the location.

mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair

Start mongod with only `--repair` option, you don't have to pass `--repairpath` option. This will attempt to repair the data. Then finally start the database

mongod --dbpath /data/db

If you follow the first method of repair then you can delete the `mongod.lock` after the repair is successful. If you follow the second method then you can delete he `mongod.lock` before performing the repair operation.

Read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/) how to safely shutdown the database, what is in mongod.lock? How you should do the repair (for example running it with same user in order to preserve the file ownership). It is also possible that the permissions to your data files has changed, you can `chown` them back, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953295/how-to-repair-my-mongodb) for more details.