# Could not run MongoDB after installed it into my Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have installed mongoDB into my Node.js (I implemented on Cloud 9 platform) with this command sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org, after I installed it, I tried to run my mongoDB with command line ./mongod . However, it showed the message like the [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25B8g.png), which made me unable to keep it running, I have used information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953295/how-to-repair-my-mongodb) to help me, but it could not work ,what may be the problem of it?

Comment: have you tried both repair and remove the lock files? Just for peace of mind do you find any lock file if you do find /where_you_store_your_db_data -name *.lock

Comment: Hi for those who need help, after I tried remove and repair again, it can work!!, thanks for your help A.P.