# Issue with mongo upgrade from 4.0 to 4.2

Tags: mongodb, nosql, upgrade

I have a single instance of mongodb, I am getting an error after upgrading mongo from 4.0 to 4.2
I cannot run mongo shell, Here is the error message:

2020-08-06T12:36:25.867+0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: Location40415: BSON field 'MinValidDocument.oplogDeleteFromPoint' is an unknown field., terminating

Answer (score 0):

This field has the following note in the source:

```
 *      oplogDeleteFromPoint: <Timestamp>,  // only exists on unclean upgrade
 *                                          // TODO (SERVER-30556): Remove after 3.6
```

And there is https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30556 though it doesn't explain what the field is.

My guess is your previous upgrade wasn't completed cleanly, maybe you could repair using 4.0 binaries. [How to repair my mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953295/how-to-repair-my-mongodb)